# Sign Driver on Win2003 32-bit

Tags: wdm

I signed a driver on Win2003 32-bit, and it can't run on Win2007 x64. I checked the properties, and there is right digit signature information.

I tried to sign on Win2008 x64, and it worked!

Does any one know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Because a 32-bit driver can't run on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: I built the driver with x64 build environemnt. It's work when I run on disable signature mode.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it effected by certificated file. It's only normal on vista+. I'm finding the root cause.